# Java stream change key of maps in list

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to use java stream to change the keys of the maps in a list, i.e., giving the original list of map is:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() {{
            add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("id", "1");
                put("display", "foo");
            }});
            add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("id", "2");
                put("display", "bar");
            }});
        }};

        System.out.println(list.toString());
```

from the above list (output for demonstration)

```
[{display=foo, id=1}, {display=bar, id=2}]
```

to a list of map:

```
[{sample=foo, sample_id=1}, {sample=bar, sample_id=2}]
```

basically, change the key "id" to "sample_id", and "display" to "sample".

Comment: It looks like you are using Maps when writing your own classes might be better. E.g. if all of the maps in the list have 2 keys, id and display, why not write a class with two fields called id and display? Also please don’t initialise lists and maps using {{ ... }}

Comment: Though against the good practices to use such `List`, `Map` combination. Yet it would be interesting to see if renaming a key(remove and put) is possible with streams. I doubt high chances of CME there though.

Comment: any reason why avoid lists / maps using {{ ... }}

Comment: found answer to the reason to avoid using {{}}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work,

```
    List<Map<String, String>> list2 = list.stream().map(e -> {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry x : e.entrySet()) {
            if (x.getKey().equals("id")) {
                map.put("sample_id", (String) x.getValue());
            } else if (x.getKey().equals("display")) {
                map.put("sample", (String) x.getValue());
            } else {
                map.put((String) x.getKey(), (String) x.getValue());
            }
        }

        return map;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Slightly more elegant,

```
    List<Map<String, String>> list3 = list.stream().map(
            e -> e.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    x -> {
                        if (x.getKey().equals("id")) {
                            return "sample_id";
                        } else if (x.getKey().equals("display")) {
                            return "sample";
                        } else {
                            return x.getKey();
                        }
                    },
                    Map.Entry::getValue))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is to stream over the `List` and map every `HashMap` into the translated `HashMap`:

```
list.stream()
    .map(this::translate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The translated `HashMap` is a copy of this `Map` with every key translated:

```
 private Map<String, String> translate(Map<String, String> map) {
        HashMap<String, String> translatedMap = new HashMap<>(map);
        translate(translatedMap, "id", "sample_id");
        translate(translatedMap, "display", "sample");
        return translatedMap;
 }
```

As we are working with stream, it's important to take a copy of the original map, since we want to avoid dealing with *shared mutable state*. Then, we translate every key of our new map, by getting the value of the key, entering the value of the new key and removing the old value:

```
private Map<String, String> translate(Map<String, String> map, String originalKey, String newKey) {
    map.put(newKey, map.remove(originalKey));
    return map;
}
```

The output is then:

```
[{display=foo, id=1}, {display=bar, id=2}]
[{sample=foo, sample_id=1}, {sample=bar, sample_id=2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original maps to stay unchanged, follow Nick Vanderhoven's approach. But if you can change the input maps, you can shorten it and don't even have to stream:

```
list.forEach(map -> {
    map.put("sample", map.remove("display"));
    map.put("sample_id", map.remove("id"));
});
```

You can of course use streams, if you want to (but still change the original maps!):

```
list.stream()
    .peek(map -> {
        map.put("sample", map.remove("display"));
        map.put("sample_id", map.remove("id"));
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -2):

Well there is an approach which you can follow.

You can override the .toString() method and can give it your own implementation.
In that way you can display it any way you want.

Comment: I think the OP wanted more that just the display of the map entries to change. They want the actual keys to change.